# BuddyPress Forum - how to display latest posts first - ordered by date - newest posts first, not the oldest posts first?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

Buddy Press forum is displaying user posts in discussion topics, by showing the oldest posts first. I would like to display the newest, latest user posts on any topic first. It doesn't make sence to see posts from 3 months ago shown on top and having to scroll down to search for the most recent posts.

I checked Word Press documentation and tried to override the posts ORDER BY to change from DESC to ASC, but it keeps on displaying the oldest posts first, so seems like BB Press is overriding it with its own internal functions.

If anybody had the same problem before and found a solution, I would greatly appreciate your help,

Sophie

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order in wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-forums/bp-forums-template.php line 1108. In the function bp_has_forum_topic_posts you can find the defaults variable. Change order to 'DESC'.

```
$defaults = array(
    'topic_id' => false,
    'per_page' => 15,
    'max'      => false,
    'order'    => 'DESC'
);
```